# count the rows of two tables

Tags: sql

I would like to count the rows of two tables, and I wrote this code:

```
SELECT count(v.id), count(c.id)
FROM votes as v, content as c
WHERE v.user_id=1 AND c.created_by=1
```

It correctly returns one row and two columns, only these two cells have exactly the same value ... and should not be so

Comment: There is no relation to v and c hence a cross join.

Comment: *"should not be so"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is doing a cross join between the two tables.  If you want to count the rows, you need something like:

```
select 'vote' as which, count(*)
from votes v
where v.user_id = 1
union all
select 'content' as which, count(*)
from content c
where c.created_by = 1
```

If you are looking for one row, two columns, use a cross join instead:

```
select vcnt, ccnt
from (select count(*) as ccnt
      from votes v
      where v.user_id = 1
     ) v cross join
     (select count(*) as ccnt
      from content c
      where c.created_by = 1
     ) c
```

Comment: That will return 1 column and 2 rows, not 1 row and 2 columns as OP states.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: About your 1st answer "Note that UNION does not guarantee the order of rows. Rows from the second operand may appear before, after, or mixed with rows from the first operand. In situations where a specific order is desired, ORDER BY must be used." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator so I'd suggest you append a description column like so select 'VotesCount' as Desc, count(*) ...... Otherwise client reading data cannot be sure which number represents votes count and which content count.

Comment: @PetarRepac . . . Not only are you correct, but I have made the same comment on other posts.  Apparently, I originally missed the desire to have two values on one row, so the original code does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count distinct values, otherwise you just count the number of rows that contain IDs in the respective column (which would be all rows except if you have `NULL`s in some IDs):

`count(DISTINCT v.id), count(DISTINCT c.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Votes.id) VotesCount,
    COUNT(Content.id) ContentCount
FROM
    Votes 
    FULL OUTER JOIN Content ON 1=2 --Ensures rows never join
```

This will join the two tables together but not match any rows. Therefore for each row in Votes, all of the Content columns will be NULL and vice versa. COUNT(ColumnName) does not count NULL values, but COUNT(*) does. Therefore this should give you your result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in the same row, then you can use a `UNION ALL` and then a `CASE` statement:

```
select max(case when col = 'voteCount' then cnt end) as voteCount,
     max(case when col = 'ContentCount' then cnt end) as ContentCount
from
(
    select count(*) cnt, 'voteCount' col
    from votes v
    where v.user_id = 1
    union all
    select count(*) cnt, 'ContentCount' col
    from content c
    where c.created_by = 1
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Count only when the selected id is not null

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(v.id,0,1)), SUM(ISNULL(c.id,0,1))
FROM votes as v, content as c
WHERE v.user_id=1 AND c.created_by=1
```

But if you need to separately count, follow this.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes as v WHERE v.user_id=1) AS Count1,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content as c WHERE c.created_by=1) AS Count2
```